# Can I use ti info (or something else) to pull back provisioning profile information for an app?

Tags: build, appcelerator

Currently putting together a rudimentary automated build process using node, for our iOS apps.  I'd like to programmatically extract provisioning profile UUIDs from Appcelerator's 'ti info' cli command.

Something along the lines of this fictional idea:

```
var my_app_profile_ID = output_from.ti.info('com.mydomain.myapp' , distribution);
```

...which would consult 'ti info' and return the distribution provisioning profile ID (or adhoc if specified) for the given app ID.

Does such a thing exist / can someone suggest a way to achieve this please?

Comment: Do you want to show the profile information only for that app which will be running your code or you want to create an app which can show the profile info for any other app??

Comment: We have numerous apps, my proposed build process will iterate through a list of code branches, git checkout and then issue a ti build.  But I need to pass the provisioning profile for each app to ti build.  So:  git checkout the com.domain.app1 branch > obtain provisioning profile for com.domain.app1 from ti info then issue a ti build using the correct provisioning profile for the app.   Then move on to com.domain.app2 , git checkout that branch, obtain the app's profile information from ti info and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the output of `ti info` as JSON:

```
$ ti info -t ios -o json
```

This should get you the info to determine the provisioning profile.